# Is Satine's Pink Diamond Dress inspired by Glinda's Dress from The Wizard of Oz?

Tags: reference, the-wizard-of-oz, moulin-rouge

In Baz Luhrmann's 2001 tragic romantic musical extravaganza, [*Moulin Rouge*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moulin_Rouge!), there is one number in particular when Satine (Nichole Kidman) performs and she is wearing a very light pink with silver diamonds and bead-work and feathered-skirted dress, sometimes referred to as the "Pink Diamond" dress.

[image]

It's not that the dresses look anything alike outside of a similar color pallet, as Satine being a courtesan would be seen as an anti-thesis to a more conservative and child-friendly Glinda the Good Witch (Billie Burke) from the  the 1939 film, [*The Wizard of Oz*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wizard_of_Oz_(1939_film)), but rather the color pallet of Glinda's dress is unique and surely iconic; a combination not often seen on film. Both dresses are also "grand" in their own rights. (And of course both actress are iconic redheads)

So I was wondering if Satine's dress was inspired by Glinda's and is this a reference to *The Wizard of Oz*?

---

Note: Nichole Kidman worked with Baz Luhrmann again on the following film *Australia*, which more blatantly referenced *The Wizard of Oz*, as the aborigine child Nullah watches the film, Nichole Kidman sings: *Somewhere over the Rainbow*, and the cinematography tries to imitate technicolor skies.

Comment: I don't see a reason to see far fetched "inspiration" if Marilyn Monroe's "Diamond are the girls best friend" is right there. It's pink, it's diamonds, it's satin.

Comment: That's another possibility for sure. I'm just looking for sources. Maybe it's both considering just how much pop culture is in Moulin Rouge in general? I mean even Georges Melies' Moon Trip/Man in the Moon gets reinvented for a scene.